# How many Namecoins are generated per block?

Tags: namecoin

Is the block reward for Namecoin halving scheduled the same way as Bitcoin, or is there a different schedule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's 50, as documented here:
http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2011/05/12/namecoin-a-dns-alternative-based-on-bitcoin.html

The reward for solving a block will [halve every 210,000 blocks (around 4 yrs), like Bitcoins](http://dot-bit.org/FAQ#What_are_the_similarities_with_Bitcoin.3F).

When namecoins are spent to register a domain name, they are destroyed. More details here:
https://github.com/vinced/namecoin/blob/master/FAQ.md

Note that even though the mining reward remains constant, the network fee to register a domain goes down quickly over time. Quote: "The network fee is initially high, but will be negligible after a couple of years. It is used to slow down the initial registration rate so that plenty of desirable names are left for late adopters."